# Math sequence puzzle

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

Complete the sequence:

5928 1411 9909 1882 5419 ...

It doesn't seem like a simple polynomial fit will work, I have tried the difference method and the quotient method. Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hard to say, can you also tell me the expiration date and the three numbers on the back?

Comment: This isn't very much information. It seems like you're getting the numbers from somewhere else. Can you provide more context?

Comment: Should we be looking for an answer that COMPLETES the sequence or CONTINUES it?

Comment: See also here: http://www.itstoohard.com/puzzle/2pXK7kIq

Comment: Polynomial fitting generates the polynomial $f(x) = $ $$2401.20833...x⁴ - 28935.4166...x³ + 120089.79166...x² - 198256.5833...x + 110629$$ which gives the next term $f(6)=106238$.

Answer (score 12):

The next number in this sequence is:

> **3655** (confirmed at the [link provided by Sleafar](http://www.itstoohard.com/puzzle/2pXK7kIq))

This sequence is based on the:

> [Middle-square method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-square_method) for generating pseudorandom numbers.
>
>  In this case, the sequence starts with a 4 digit seed (5928), which is then squared (35141184). The middle 4 digits of the result become the next number in the sequence. If the result is less than 8 digits, leading zeroes are provided.

So, this sequence progresses as:

> ```
> 5928  35141184
> 1411  01990921
> 9909  98188281
> 1882  03541924
> 5419  29365561
> 3655  13359025
> 3590  12888100
> ```